# python jinja2: using variable in template with conditional

Tags: python, jinja2

I have this:

```
{% for row in data: %}
    <td
            {{'value={{row['value']}}' if 'showit' in map and header in map['showit'] and 'value' in row}}
    > ... </td>
{% endfor %}
```

But obviously that's not working. Trying to add an HTML attribute to the cell using a secondary column in the `row` dict. Any thoughts?

Comment: expression should be in {% ... %}. you can check the expression and then use {{row['value']}}.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your trouble is with the syntax getting the `row['value']`, concatenate the strings rather than trying to nest the `{{ }}`s:

`{{ 'value=' + row['value'] if True }}`

Replace the `True` with your condition of course. If you need to quote the param:

`{{ 'value="' + row['value'] + '"' if True }}`

As @Reza-S4 suggested you can also put the conditional outside the print statement to be a little clearer:

```
{% if 'showit' in map and header in map['showit'] and 'value' in row: %}
  value="{{ row['value'] }}"
{% endif %}
```